# CheckBluetoot function terminates app Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, bluetooth

Hi I'm working with delphi XE5 IDE, and had a demo source code for bluetooth communication. In the demo app everything is working fine, but when I start a blank project, and add all the uses and initialization needed for the bluetooth, my app sudnely  terminates. In debug I found out that in CheckBluetooth function happens something that causes this problem. But with the original demo app, on the same tablet at the same conditions everything is ok. 
Maybe there are some project settings, mean directory path compiling or build option that I miss? Pleas help in that, here is the part of the code:

```
procedure TTabbedwithNavigationForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  s:string;
  i:integer;
  list:TStringList;
begin
  list:=TStringList.Create;
  s:=checkBluetooth; // Verifica se o bluetooth está habilitado
  if pos('disabled',s)<>0 then begin
    ShowMessage('Por favor, ligue o bluetooth e tente novamente!');
    exit
  end;

  // Esta é a melhor conexão SPP UUID para conectar com um dispositivo serial Bluetooth
  uid:=TJUUID.JavaClass.fromString(stringtojstring('00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB'));

  list.Clear;
  list.AddStrings(getbonded);    // Faz uma lista com dispositivos pareados

  listview1.Items.Clear;  // Lampa a lista e a reconstrói
  listview1.BeginUpdate;
  for i := 0 to list.Count-1 do begin
    listview1.Items.Add;
    listview1.Items.Item[i].Text:=list[i].Split(['='])[0];
    listview1.Items.Item[i].Detail:=list[i].Split(['='])[1];
  end;
  listview1.EndUpdate
end;
```

The problematic part:

```
s:=checkBluetooth; // Verifica se o bluetooth está habilitado
```

---

As I said, I used the code from a complete project that works fine.
In debug I found out that the checkBluetooth function fail. Then I did step into debug to see which is the problematic step.

```
function checkBluetooth:string;
var
  x:JBluetoothAdapter;
  s:String;
  addr:string;
begin
  x:=TJBluetoothAdapter.JavaClass.getDefaultAdapter;
  s:=jstringtostring(x.getName);
  if x.isEnabled then result:=s+'(enabled) '+jstringtostring(x.getAddress)
    else result:=s+'(disabled)';
end;
```

This part is ok,

```
x:=TJBluetoothAdapter.JavaClass.getDefaultAdapter;
```

and then the app is terminates itself.

But once again, this code is working in the demo project. So there is no error in this lines, maybe some missing set up in the project options, or some missing privileges and my app cannot access to bluetooth...

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some debugging. Step through the working code. Step through the broken code. Identify the difference and focus your attention there. You haven't provided any relevant code here.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was the problem, missed to add permission for my app to use the tablet's adapter.

> Add BLUETOOTH permission to manifest.xml in XE5 IDE - Project -
>   Options - Uses Permissions

[Usefull site for all this stuff](http://www.pclviewer.com/android/)